# How discover the device /dev

Tags: nodes, yocto, udev

on my embedded device (RTOS Yocto) there are two serial link (RS232 and RS485) but I don't have a full documentation so I 'm not able to find the right node ( under /dev ) to open for R\W operation
The *.dtsi file is not help me and udev shell also, maybe because I get several info but not how is engagged the node

Any suggestion?

P

Comment: Please provide links (the BSP layer, dtsi file, ...)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it correctly, then you should have a look at dmesg, and look for the type of node you are searching. For example:

```
dmesg | grep -i tty
```

Comment: Yes, seems the unique solution with a check on dtsi files. Thansk